# Oracle APEX: Rich Text Editor won't work in jQuery dialog box

Tags: jquery, oracle, modal-dialog, ckeditor, oracle-apex

I am using APEX 4.2.4 and I try to create a dialog box that contains a Rick Text Editor (CKEditor3).

I added a Rich Text Editor field in a region (region id: `#notification`) and set `style="display:none;"` to this region. Then I have a button that when clicked, it executes the following JS code and triggers the modal:

```
function notification() {
  var jqDialog = $('#notification').dialog(
    { modal: true,
      autoOpen: true,
      width: '500px',
      closeOnEscape: true
    });
}
```

When the button is clicked, the modal opens as it should, but the iframe for the editor is empty (cannot click in it and add content).

If I remove the editor from the modal and just render it with the page load normaly, I see the editor and it's editable without a problem. But from the moment I hide it (either with `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden;`) and then use the modal to display it, it won't be editable anymore.

It doesn't work in Firefox 27.0.1 and Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m but it works in IE 10 and 11.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is a bug, which was described there http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4727. But as for me this solution doesn't work. Due to the nature of the apex it is impossible to put a jquery-ui-dialog-patch-ckeditor.js file immediately after init ckeditor file in <head> tag. The only one solution works:

1. In "Page Attributes" in region "Execute when Page Loads" write:

   ```
   $('#notification').dialog({
       modal: true,
       autoOpen: true,
       width: 500,
       closeOnEscape: true,
       autoOpen: false
   });
   ```
2. Then, in your dynamic action, on event 'click' for your button you can redefine dialog options and open dialog:

   ```
   $('#notification').dialog({
       modal: true,
       autoOpen: true,
       width: 700,
       height: 400,
       closeOnEscape: true,
       autoOpen: false
   });

   $('#notification').dialog("open");
   ```

It works on all modern browsers, including IE 10 and 11.